# Deque implementation using Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, performance, array, deque

I have written code for the basic implementation of a Deque in C++ using Array(pointer). Please review my code and suggest ways to make it simpler, compact, and efficient. Also would appreciate feedback on any aspect of my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class queue
{
private:
    int size = 0, front = -1, rear = -1;
    float *arr;

public:
    queue(int inputSize)
    {
        size = inputSize;
        arr = (float *)malloc(size * sizeof(float));
    }
    int isEmpty(queue *q)
    {
        if (q->front == q->rear)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int isFull(queue *q)
    {
        if (q->rear == q->size - 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    void enqueueR(queue *q, int data)
    {
        if (isFull(q))
        {
            std::cout << data << " cannot be entered as Queue is Full\n";
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear++;
            q->arr[q->rear] = data;
        }
    }
    void enqueueF(queue *q, int data)
    {
        if (isFull(q))
        {
            std::cout << data << " cannot be entered as Queue is Full\n";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = front + 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                q->arr[i + 1] = q->arr[i];
            }
            q->arr[q->front + 1] = data;
            q->rear++;
        }
    }
    void dequeueF(queue *q)
    {
        if (isEmpty(q))
        {
            std::cout << "Queue is Empty\n";
        }
        else
        {
            q->front++;
            std::cout << "The removed value is: " << q->arr[q->front] << "\n";
        }
    }
    void dequeueR(queue *q)
    {
        if (isEmpty(q))
        {
            std::cout << "Queue is Empty\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The removed value is: " << q->arr[q->rear] << "\n";
            q->rear--;
        }
    }
    void queueTraversal(queue *q)
    {
        std::cout << "The queue is as follows:\n";
        for (int i = front + 1; i <= rear; i++)
        {
            std::cout << q->arr[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advice 1**

`queue` stores a queue of `float` values. Why not to rename to `float_queue`?

**Advice 2**

`arr = (float *)malloc(size * sizeof(float));`

You can write:

`arr = new float[size];`

**Advice 3**

Your class misses the destructor, which should call `delete[] arr;` on the queue. Thus, you leak RAM.

**Advice 4**

`int size = 0, front = -1, rear = -1;`

`int` supports some negative values, but they are meaningless in this context; change to `size_t`, which is concieved as the type for counting/indexing stuff.

**Advice 5**

```
int isEmpty(queue *q)
{
    if (q->front == q->rear)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why do you ask for `queue* q` argument when you can simply refer to the members of the class? Same observation applies to other relevant methods.

**Advice 6**

```
if (isFull(q))
{
    std::cout << data << " cannot be entered as Queue is Full\n";
}
```

This is a no-no in the professional data structure development; throw an exception instead.

**Advice 7**

```
queueTraversal(queue *q)
```

This is asking for [**iterators**](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/).

**Suggestion 1**

I suggest you consult a professional C++-developer (obviously not me), whether it makes sense to implement:

1. copy constructor
2. copy assignment
3. move constructor
4. move assignment

**All in all**

I had this implementation in mind:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::copy;
using std::logic_error;

class float_queue
{
private:
    size_t size;
    size_t max_capacity;
    size_t front_index;
    float* storage_array;

public:
    float_queue(size_t _max_capacity) : size(0),
                                        max_capacity(_max_capacity), 
                                        front_index(0), 
                                        storage_array(new float[_max_capacity]) {}

    float_queue(const float_queue& other) : 
        size(other.size),
        max_capacity(other.max_capacity),
        front_index(other.front_index) {

        storage_array = new float[other.max_capacity];
        copy(other.storage_array,
             other.storage_array + other.max_capacity, 
             storage_array);
    }

    float_queue(float_queue&& other) :
        size(other.size),
        max_capacity(other.max_capacity),
        front_index(other.front_index),
        storage_array(other.storage_array) {

        other.size = 0;
        other.max_capacity = 0;
        other.front_index = 0;
        other.storage_array = nullptr;
    }

    float_queue& operator=(const float_queue& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            float* new_array = new float[other.max_capacity];
            copy(other.storage_array, 
                 other.storage_array + other.max_capacity, 
                 new_array);

            delete[] storage_array;
            storage_array = new_array;
            max_capacity = other.max_capacity;
            size = other.size;
            front_index = other.front_index;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    float_queue& operator=(float_queue&& other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            size = other.size;
            front_index = other.front_index;
            max_capacity = other.max_capacity;
            storage_array = other.storage_array;

            other.size = 0;
            other.front_index = 0;
            other.max_capacity = 0;
            other.storage_array = nullptr;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    ~float_queue() {
        size = 0;
        max_capacity = 0;
        front_index = 0;
        delete[] storage_array;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    int isFull()
    {
        return size == max_capacity;
    }

    void prepend(float f) {
        if (isFull()) {
            throw logic_error{"Prepending while full."};
        }

        size_t new_front_index;

        if (front_index == 0) {
            new_front_index = max_capacity - 1;
        }
        else {
            new_front_index = front_index - 1;
        }

        size++;
        storage_array[new_front_index] = f;
        front_index = new_front_index;
    }
    
    void append(float f) {
        if (isFull()) {
            throw logic_error{"Appending while full."};
        }

        size_t append_index = (front_index + size) % max_capacity;
        size++;
        storage_array[append_index] = f;
    }

    float removeHead() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw logic_error{"Removing a head from empty queue."};
        }

        float rv = storage_array[front_index];
        front_index = (front_index + 1) % max_capacity;
        size--;
        return rv;
    }

    float removeTail() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw logic_error{"Removing a tail from empty queue."};
        }

        float rv = storage_array[(front_index + size - 1) % max_capacity];
        size--;
        return rv;
    }
};
```

Note that the above code snippet is not tested for bugs/design errors; it's only for my semi-professional reference. Good luck!